# Inserting php arrays into mysqli database rows?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

In my MySQLi database, I have 2 columns in the table. One is 'author' and the other is 'books'. I have a variable called '$author' and an array called '$books' which contains unknown numbers of values.

I want to populate column 'books' with values inside array '$books' and in the other column variable '$author' which will remain constant in all rows.

Please help. It will be even more appreciated if you provide it in procedural way instead of OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$author` is a string and `$books` is an array of integers,

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO your_table (books,author) VALUES(";
foreach($books as $book_data){

    $sql .= "($book_data,'$author'),";

}
$sql = rtrim($sql, ",") . ")";
//Execute the query
```

This will insert every `$books` variable as a new row with the constant `$author`.